# Push the content when drawer is open

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm new on vuetify, I read the documentation related about component that I used above. But I didn't found any solution that make it happen.
I hope my screenshot explain it, I just wanna push my content and didn't overlap it.

When `drawer` not opened:
[image]

When `drawer` is open:
[image]

NavBar.vue

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar flat app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon class="grey--text" @click="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-app-bar-title class="text-uppercase grey--text">
        <span class="font-weight-light">Todo</span>
        <span>Ninja</span>
      </v-app-bar-title>
      <v-spacer />
      <v-btn text color="grey">
        <span>Sign Out</span>
        <v-icon>mdi-exit-to-app</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      app
      temporary
      hide-overlay
      v-model="drawer"
      class="primary"
    >
      <v-list color="primary">
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(menu, i) in menus"
          :key="i"
          router
          :to="menu.route"
        >
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon v-text="menu.icon" class="white--text" />
          </v-list-item-icon>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="menu.text" class="white--text" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app class="grey lighten-4">
    <NavBar />
    <v-content class="mx-4 mb-4">
      <router-view />
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just found the solution in here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props

Just remove the `temporary` props for make it work, maybe I will learn about how to close it when click outside of navbar later.